# Chrome extension Web Request doesn't show info

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrequest

I was looking for without success. 
I want to get the status of my requests from my extension but I can not get it.

**Manifiest**

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Pixel Checker TT",
  "description": "This extension validate your pixels and its requests",
  "version": "1.6",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": ["sources/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js","content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://*.mydomain.co/",
    "*://*.myotherdomain.co/"
  ]
}
```

**popup.js or background code**

```
 chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
            for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {

                console.log(details.requestHeaders[i].url);
                console.log(details.requestHeaders[i].statusCode);
            }

        },
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ['blocking','requestHeaders']);
```

The problem is that I dont have errors just aren not printed the info. I also tried to put the info in a div with $('#pixelsFound').text(details.requestHeaders[i].url) 
but doesn't work too.

Comment: What is purpose if `['blocking','requestHeaders']`?

Comment: Should I remove them ? example please

Comment: Have you tried without `['blocking','requestHeaders']`?

Comment: But it needs a param I think. I will Try it.

Comment: Doesnt work , the onCompleted is not recognized men,